# Configure create-react-app to generate one js file on build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, create-react-app

I have a react app created with create-react-app.

I want to serve it as a static site from azure blob storage [(see link)](https://www.vincentvanderwalt.com/2018-09-11-run-static-reactjs-on-azure-blob/), currently when running npm run build it creates an index.html file and a css file and 3 js files.

I want to configure the webpack to output only 1 js file when running npm run build so I only need to reference 1 js file in the index.html file.

Comment: what is your question? please elaborate!

Comment: @MosheSlavin I added more details to the question.